# Is there any way to restrict a number to accept only one dot using angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

if a user inputs a number like 23.4. ,then it should not accept the 2nd dot as the number has already a decimal point.Again if someone puts a number like 2... ,then also it should accept only 2. and rest dots should not be displayed.Can anyone suggest me how to do this?

Comment: This isn't really an Angular problem, more of a HTML problem. You should look for some sort of masked input. If you're using your own version of jQuery with Angular, you could use http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/

Comment: Why not create a directive that it can associate with and upon input change, it would scan the input number and only use the first decimal it sees as its validation?

Answer (score 1):

You can write a simple directive for this. For example:

```
app.directive('restrictDecimal', function() {
    return {
        scope: {},
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, controller) {
            element.bind('keypress', function(e) {
                if (e.keyCode === 46 && this.value.indexOf('.') >= 0) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    return false;
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

What it does is preventing from typing a `.` if there is already one.

Demo [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/Hvb9OnTJrH8JPeYAKgsP?p=preview).

However consider using proper more advanced validation and input masking. This is just a basic solution (without handling paste event).

Comment: its not working.try giving input as 1.....,you can see it accepts all dots.

Comment: Of course it will not work you paste incorrect number in the field. I just gave you a hint how you can write custom directive. You just need to handle paste event.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to make sure the input is a valid number, out of the box Angular's form validation will check for numbers if your input has `type="number"`

```
<input type="number" ng-model="myNum">
```

The documentation at http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:input.number has a good demo of this been implimented.

And, as a bonus mobile input will give you the number focused keyboard for easier entry.

But for more advanced cases, @dfsq 's answer will set you on the right path.

Answer (score -1):

say if the html is something like this:

```
<input id="number" name="dummy">
```

Then you can do something like this:

```
jQuery('#number').keyup(function(){
    var value = this.val().match(\d\+\.\d\d);
    this.val(value);
})
```